# Pyspark - dataframe..write - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to convert csv files into parquet using pyspark.

```
parquet_file = s3://bucket-name/prefix/

parquet_df.write.format("parquet").option("compression", "gzip").save(parquet_file).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
```

I am trying to overwrite parquet file(s) but getting the following error. Could you please help.

> Error occurred - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/tmp/ma-test-csv-to-parquet-glue-job-2", line 173, in  result
> = write_to_parquet(nn_df1) File "/tmp/ma-test-csv-to-parquet-glue-job-2", line 147, in
> write_to_parquet
> parquet_df.write.format("parquet").option("compression",
> "gzip").save(parquet_file).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) AttributeError:
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'

Answer (score 0):

The writing mode should be specified for [`DataFrameWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html) not after `save` as you did (which returns nothing "None", thus the error message):

```
parquet_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").option("compression","gzip").save(parquet_file)
```